# Inserting correct x and y values in DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a website with images that you can drag around with the mouse, all these images have their own x and y positions, but I need to pass these values into a MySQL database. I have almost managed to do so, but all the images get the same x and y values in the database. 
Soo here is my `house.php` which has 3 images that I can drag around, all these images have a class that increment by 1. So it's image: `item0`, `item1`, `item2`

```
<div id="house_wall1">
     <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
        <?php // echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); 

        $n = 0;
        $item_number = 0;
        //Array which iterates over all objects in a given users object_id
        $objects[$n];

        for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsize; $i++) {
            if ($i == $objects[$n]) {
                $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
                $stmt->prepare('SELECT x, y, src FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE objects.object_id = ?'); 
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
                );
                if ($stmt->execute()) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $src);
                    while($stmt->fetch()) {
                        echo '<img onMouseOver="houseAjax()" src="' . $src . '" class="item' . $item_number . '" style="position:relative; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 'px;">';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
                }
                $stmt->close();
                $n++;
                $item_number++;
            }
        }
        ?>

        <!-- <div id="start"></div> -->
        <!-- <div id="stop"></div> -->
        <ul>
            <li id="posX"></li>
            <li id="posY"></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- <button onclick="houseAjax()">Save positions</button> -->
    </div>
```

So when you move over the images with your mouse, the PHP runs a AJAX call to this script:
(house_ajax.js)

```
    function houseAjax(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            $.post("update_house.php",{newx: xPos, newy: yPos},function(result){
              });
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","update_house.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

... Which uses this PHP script to insert the x and y values into the database
(update_house.php)

```
    <?php
        require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

        $newX = $_POST['newx'];
        $newY = $_POST['newy'];

    $object_id = 1;
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 2) {

        /* Register a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = ?, y = ? WHERE user_id=? AND object_id=?')) {

            /* Bind parametres */
            $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $newX, $newY, $user_id, $object_id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $user_id = 1;
                $object_id = $i;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terribly wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $object_id++;
            $i++;
    }
?>
```

So I lose each of the y and x values somewhere in this journey through numerous lines of code. I think it has something to do with the variables `$newX = $_POST['newx'];` and `$newY = $_POST['newy'];` in `update_house.php` but I have no idea what to do to get this working and I feel like I have tried everything for several hours. I hope someone can help me with this problem even though it's one of the larger projects to stick your head into. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The positions are grapped by JS in this file named `house_position.js`

```
var offset = 0,
        xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0,
        item_number = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    while(item_number<3) {
        $('.item' + item_number ).draggable({

        containment: '#house_wall1',

        drag: function(){
            offset = $(this).position();
            xPos = offset.left;
            yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        },

        // Find original position of dragged image.
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // Show start dragged position of image.
            var Startpos = $(this).position();
            $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
        },

        // Find position where image is dropped.
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // Show dropped position.
            var Stoppos = $(this).position();
            $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
        }
    });
    item_number++;
    }
});
```

Comment: your never passing the id of the object you are moving so you are always only updating the object with the id of 1

Comment: @cmorrissey Can you specify closer where in the code you mean?

Comment: Probably a problem with the JS variables xPos, yPos in `{newx: xPos, newy: yPos}` show us how do you grab the current position

Comment: @ShlomiHassid I have added the JS that grab the current position. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are exactly doing but here are some thoughts:

1. Your `draggable` function - you are declaring the `xPos yPos` variables outside of the function. In this case any picture you will drag will update those variables - I assume you want each image to have it's own position variables saved.... so create an array or object that will hold those values separately.
2. In your `update_house.php` - you are only updating `object_id='1'`. You are wrapping the sqli method with a WHILE loop that will only execute once I don't think its what you meant.
3. you are executing the the `houseAjax()` on mouse over??? I think you better execute it on drag stops, just add the function call to the stop section (at the end) of the draggable method.

I bet its **1**.

Here is my version (not tested ~ can't test) - its a good place to start from:

house.php:

```
<div id="house_wall1">
 <?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
    <?php // echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); 

    $n = 0;
    $item_number = 0;
    //Array which iterates over all objects in a given users object_id
    $objects[$n];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsize; $i++) {
        if ($i == $objects[$n]) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
            $stmt->prepare('SELECT x, y, src FROM house_room1 INNER JOIN objects ON house_room1.object_id=objects.object_id WHERE objects.object_id = ?'); 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $i
            );
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $stmt->bind_result($x, $y, $src);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo '<img src="' . $src . '" class="item' . $item_number . '" style="position:relative; left:' . $x . 'px; top:' . $y . 'px;">';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $n++;
            $item_number++;
        }
    }
    ?>

    <!-- <div id="start"></div> -->
    <!-- <div id="stop"></div> -->
    <ul>
        <li id="posX"></li>
        <li id="posY"></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- <button onclick="houseAjax()">Save positions</button> -->
</div>
```

house_ajax.js

```
    function houseAjax(object_id){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        $.post("update_house.php",{newx: xPos[object_id], newy: yPos[object_id], object_id: object_id},function(result){
          });
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","update_house.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

update_house.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/db_connect.php');

    $newX = $_POST['newx'];
    $newY = $_POST['newy'];

    $object_id = $_POST['object_id'];

    /* Register a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE house_room1 SET x = ?, y = ? WHERE user_id=? AND object_id=?')) {

        /* Bind parametres */
        $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $newX, $newY, $user_id, $object_id);

            /* Insert the parameter values */
            $user_id = 1;

            /* Execute the query */
            $stmt->execute();

            /* Close statement */
            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            /* Something went wrong */
            echo 'Something went terribly wrong'     . $mysqli->error;
        }
?>
```

house_position.js:

```
var xPos=new Array();
    xPos[0] = 0;
    xPos[1] = 0;
    xPos[2] = 0;

var yPos=new Array();
    yPos[0] = 0;
    yPos[1] = 0;
    yPos[2] = 0;

var offset=new Array(); 
    offset[0] = 0;
    offset[1] = 0;
    offset[2] = 0;

var item_number = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

  while(item_number<3) {
    $('.item' + item_number ).draggable({

    containment: '#house_wall1',

    drag: function(){
        var cur1 = item_number;
        offset[cur1] = $(this).position();
        xPos[cur1] = offset[cur1].left;
        yPos[cur1] = offset[cur1].top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos[cur1]);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos[cur1]);
    },

    // Find original position of dragged image.
    start: function(event, ui) {
        // Show start dragged position of image.
        var Startpos = $(this).position();
        $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
    },

    // Find position where image is dropped.
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // Show dropped position.
        var cur2 = item_number;
        var Stoppos = $(this).position();
        $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
        // save new position:
        houseAjax(cur2);
    }
});
item_number++;
}
});
```

Comment: I see you have added a lot, I will just look it through, meanwhile; I tested your code and it doesn't update any of the images positions into the database, it simply keeps the same positions as the database holds and nothing updates when the images are dragged update: I will just try and update the stop drag function

Comment: Yes it will probably not work you have to adjust it to your code correctly its just an example of the three thoughts I mentiond...

Comment: Yeah, but you seem to understand it pretty well, the three thoughts you mentioned is exactly what I believe could be wrong about my code. If you like, I can send you a link to see it? That might make it easier because I think you're very close to getting it right

Comment: Send me - What happen exactly if you update the code exactly as I wrote it (all of files).

Comment: Update and add a table scheme and data example too please

Comment: Okay maybe if we put this conversation to a chatroom instead, I can provide you with all the information

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48115/discussion-between-user3287771-and-shlomi-hassid)